# Laravel меню страниц из базы данных

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6

Хочу сделать правильно. Задумано, что можно создавать страницы на сайте через панель администратора. Создана таблицы `pages` в базе данных. Модель `Page` и контроллер-ресурс `PageController`. Также настроен роут.

В контроллере `PageController` для отображения страницы в методе `show` возвращаю вид и данные для отображения. Тут всё понятно. Запроси страницу - получил.

Когда буду писать админку, то задействую остальные методы контроллера `PageController`: `store`, `destroy` и другие, включая `index` - для отображения списка всех страниц. Таким образом одна таблица в базе данных - одна модель, один роут-ресурс, один контроллер.

Однако на сайте есть меню, вынесенное как отдельное представление. Возникает вопрос - как динамически генерировать меню. Метод `index` контроллера `PageController` занят (для админки; смотри выше). К тому же моё меню - это отдельное представление, ребёнок родителя. Туда данные так просто не передашь - придётся передавать в каждый вид-родитель, а это куча ненужного кода, ведь меню выводится на каждой странице сайта.

Вот собственно и вопрос - как выкрутиться? Как получить данные для отображения этого меню? Так сказать True Laravel Way.

Comment: Во-первых, контроллер можно разделить на два `AdminPageController` и просто `PageController`, чтобы не мешать разделы. Тогда вам освобождаются новые экшены. Во-вторых, раз меню генерируется при показе какой-либо страницы, то бишь в методе `show`, то и генерация должна как-то происходить там, с помощью какого-нибудь сервиса.

Comment: Ну а передавать данные то как? У меня меню это в 10 видах, например подключается. Не на прямую  - через наследование. Вывожу я например какой-то вид для отображения, скажем, поста в блоге. И что? Мне в контроллере там искать и передавать список страниц. А потом в другом контроллере на вывод, например, товара - тоже искать страницы и выводить?

Comment: @u_mulder есть же какой-то подход?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этих целей следует использовать [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers). Можно назначать данные определённым видам и т.п. Очень удобно.

Comment: Можете указать что это ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько Завтра только смогу. Тут ограничение

Answer (score 0):

Недавно делал то же самое.

Я делал так:

1. Каждый элемент меню хранит id родителя. У тех, кто не имеет родителя id родителя равен null.
2. Выстраиваем в контроллере массив следующим образом: в начало кладем самых старших, потом их детей(не внуков) и так далее.
3. Дальше за один проход просто вставляем элементы друг в друга. Конструкция массива позволяет. Вставлять можно в domdocumet c php или прямо в страничку c ajax.

Таким образом мы не будем делать много действий на фронт энде и прописывать меню.

А таблицу со страницами через внешний ключ подключим к элементу меню.
Т.е. будет 2 контроллера NavigationElementsController и PagesController.

Comment: вопрос не в том, как построить это меню, а в том, как его пробрасывать в любой вид